# Where can I find a comprehensive Javascript iframe programming reference?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

There is a part of my web application that might end up making heavy use of iframes (to be able to serve arbritrary content from elsewhere). I know there are many cross-domain and cross-browser quirks I need to worry about so **is there any reference out there that has everything I need in one place?** Is there an "iframe Bible"?

Comment: Alex Sexton has given a [nice presentation](http://alexsexton.com/?p=154) on the subject.

Comment: @Pointy: I remember seeing that presentation but the video format doesn't make it very friendly as a reference.

Comment: @missingno Iframes are merely nested windows. As long as you know how to access child windows and parent windows, you should be fine... What more could you be asking for?

Comment: The way you access the windows depends on browser, what the code on each frame can do depends on their domains and there are many little workarounds and tricks people have developed over time . What annoys me that everything I find only mentions one aspect or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not an iframe bible, but it's worth a read:

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/